# How to get Chrome/browser to accept my SSL cert (signed by intermediate cert for my own CA)

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate-store

I come from a DEV background, but trying to improve my sec/ops skills to become more versatile.

I've set up my own local certificate authority following [this guide](https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/index.html) (albeit fairly loosely).

I successfully created a root pair (key & cert), an intermediate pair, and a server pair for test.mydomain.com.

I then configured nginx as a service proxy to an Node.js web API (served by Express FWIW). Both nginx and the nodejs service are containerised and I'm just using docker-compose to run this locally. I've also added a hosts entry so that I can access my service using test.mydomain.com. Eventually I want to implement the service-proxy/sidecar pattern in Kubernetes (where nginx and the (micro)service run in the same pod), but for now I'm just trying to get it working in docker.

It was all working over HTTP, so the next step is to get it working for HTTPS (where TLS terminates at the nginx service-proxy and the request then gets proxied to the Node.js service over HTTP). It is working, but I can't get my browser (Chrome running in Windows) to accept my certificate.

[image]

I've tried a few combinations of importing certificates into Windows certificate stores including:

- importing the root certificate into the trusted root CAs certificate store
- importing the intermediate certificate into the intermediate CAs certificate store
- chaining the root and intermediate certs and importing to the root CAs certificate store

but I can't get Chrome to accept my certificate.

FYI nginx is configured as follows

```
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/test.mydomain.com.cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/test.mydomain.com.key.pem;
```

Should I be chaining the server, intermediate, & root certs for the `ssl_certificate` setting in nginx?.. and what certificate (or chained certificate) should I be importing to which certificate store?

I also noticed there's a `ssl_trusted_certificate` nginx setting, which I'm not sure if I should be using...

Cheers,
Ryan.

Comment: you have any idea of cert-bot ? if you are using Nginx or apache you can use cert-bot instead of creating the certificate and CSR and everything it will be easy to do automatic using the certbot. which will generate the certificate and add it inside the Nginx block.

Comment: Thanks @HarshManvar. I had briefly looked at cert-manager (which I think is kinda similar). I wanted to get the basics all working (really just to improve my understanding) before looking a bit deeper into this... but it's definitely on the list of things I want to look in to...

Comment: are you using cert-manager in kubernetes?

Comment: No, but I've briefly read about it... coming from a DEV background a lot of the concepts confused me and I didn't really know where to start. This is part of the reason why I'm trying to get internal/private CA up and running, so that I get a deeper understanding about all the security concepts. FYI., the company I work for is moving to K8s, and we'll probably want to use something like cert-manager/certbot for automatic provisioning and management of TLS certs...

Comment: ohk got it no issues you can follow this example is so easy to setup ingress, cert-manager : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes let me know if any question are there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I finally got it all working. There were a few things...

I managed to get things working in Firefox first, but Chrome was still failing. This was the clue that I needed - turns out Chrome requires certificates to include one or more Subject Alternative Names as opposed to just a Common Name (which is evidently acceptible to Firefox).

I had to configure Subject Alternative Names when I created and signed the certificate request.

The rest was fairly easy.

In nginx, `ssl_certificate` is pointing at a chained certificate (server cert + intermediate cert).

and then I had to import the root certificate into the trusted root CAs for the local computer.

Restart chrome and voila:

[image]